# Is rand() predictable in SQL Server

Tags: t-sql

Recently I was told that numbers generated using `rand()` in `SQL Server 2008` returns predictable number sequence. Is it true?

```
declare @RandNum int
set @RandNum=RAND()*100
print @RandNum
```

Comment: This [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) addresses this topic. Yes, the numbers are predictable, if you know the *seed* value. Normally you don't know this, therefore they are not predictable. Answer: Theoretically yes, practically no.

Comment: Any computer generated random number is only psudo random, and therefor, at least in theory, is predictable. However, this doesn't mean that it's easy to predict them.